# NSLayoutConstraint inside UITableViewCell crashes app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I'm trying to position an image in the center of a `UITableViewCell` with `NSLayoutConstraint`s. I'm using the code below for that:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *cn = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.image
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                     toItem:cell.contentView
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                 multiplier:1
                                   constant:200];
[self.image addConstraint: cn];

cn = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.image
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                     toItem:cell.contentView
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                 multiplier:1
                                   constant:200];
[self.image addConstraint:cn];
```

Also, I would like the image to be 80% of the `UITableViewCell`s height and have the same width - so it's square. However, currently my app crashes and throws this error: `Impossible to set up layout with view hierarchy unprepared for constraint.`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably should add constraints to `cell.contentView`, not to `self.image`. Not sure though. Googling the error gives many cues too, also on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, I had to add the image to the `cell.contentView`, so that it was actually available as a subview.

This is the completed working code:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *cn = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.image
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:cell.contentView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                         multiplier:0.7
                                                           constant:0];
    [cell.contentView addConstraint: cn];

    cn = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.image
                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                         toItem:cell.contentView
                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                     multiplier:0.7
                                       constant:0];
    [cell.contentView addConstraint:cn];

    NSLayoutConstraint *constraintX = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.image attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:cell.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0f constant:0];
    NSLayoutConstraint *constraintY = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.image attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:cell.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.0f constant:0];
    [cell.contentView addConstraint:constraintX];
    [cell.contentView addConstraint:constraintY];
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what is "self.image" referring to? Is it a property of your View Controller (this would be definitely wrong)? Seems to me it should be "cell.image" where each of your cells should have it's own reference to an image.

Comment: It's an image (a profile picture) added to the cell.